# terraform :An input variable with the name "AMI" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "AMI" {} block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to terraform.
I was trying my bit on terrafrom

I have this bit in var.tfvars

```
variable "AWS_REGION" {    
default = "me-south-1"
}
variable "AMI" {
    type = "map"
    
    default ={
        me-south-1 = "ami-01b735b798*******"
        us-east-1 = "ami-0c2a1acae666******"
    }
}
```

and I am trying to create an ec2  in VPC by

```
resource "aws_instance" "terraform-web" {
ami = "${lookup(var.AMI, var.AWS_REGION)}"
instance_type = "t3.micro"
```

which is giving me the above-mentioned error.

Could anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way terraform works is:

variables.tf -- all variables are declared in this file

vars.tfvars -- all values are passed via this file. Name can be anything. should end with tfvars.

You don't need to use lookup just var.<variable_name> is enough!

**ec2.tf:**

```
    resource "aws_instance" "terraform-web" {
    ami = var.ami_id
    instance_type = "t3.micro"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "ami_id" {
    type = "string"
    default = "xxxx"

}
```

**vars.tfvars**

```
ami_id = "yyyyy"
```

Comment: Variables can be defined in any `.tf` file in the directory. `variables.tf` is mostly a convention so that a user of a module can see all the possible and required input variables in one place. You should also mention about how some tfvars files are automatically loaded (eg `terraform.tfvars`) while others need to be specified on the command line.

Comment: The lookup point is also incorrect if you look at their data type. But instead of doing an old school map lookup like you had to do pre 0.7 (back in 2016!) you should be encouraging the usage of the `aws_ami` (and possibly `aws_region` as well) data source instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR how would I be implementing  the new way ?