# How to launch multiple AWS EC2 instances from a single VPC using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-vpc, aws-route-table

Is it possible to launch multiple ec2 instances from terraform using a single VPC? I'm building something which requires multiple instances to be launched from the same region and I'm doing all this using Terraform. But there's a limit in AWS VPC: per region only 5 VPCs are allowed. What I've been doing until now is each time when I need to launch an instance I create a separate VPC for it in terraform. Below is the code for reference:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}
# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
  access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  secret_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

# 1. Create vpc

resource "aws_vpc" "prod-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "production"
  }
}

# 2. Create Internet Gateway

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id


}

# 3. Create Custom Route Table

resource "aws_route_table" "prod-route-table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  route {
    ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"
    gateway_id      = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Prod"
  }
}

# 4. Create a Subnet

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"

  tags = {
    Name = "prod-subnet"
  }
}

# 5. Associate subnet with Route Table

resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet-1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.prod-route-table.id
}

# 6. Create Security Group to allow port 22,80,443

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_web" {
  name        = "allow_web_traffic"
  description = "Allow Web inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "HTTPS"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
    ingress {
    description = "self"
    from_port   = 8000
    to_port     = 8000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_web"
  }
}

# 7. Create a network interface with an ip in the subnet that was created in step 4

resource "aws_network_interface" "web-server-nic" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.subnet-1.id
  private_ips     = ["10.0.1.50"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_web.id]

}

# 8. Assign an elastic IP to the network interface created in step 7

resource "aws_eip" "one" {
  vpc                       = true
  network_interface         = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
  associate_with_private_ip = "10.0.1.50"
  depends_on                = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
}

output "server_public_ip" {
  value = aws_eip.one.public_ip
}

# 9. Create Ubuntu server and install/enable apache2

resource "aws_instance" "web-server-instance" {
  ami               = var.AMI_ID
  instance_type     = "g4dn.xlarge"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
  key_name          = "us-east-2"
  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
  }
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = "200"
  }
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.training_profile.name
  depends_on = [aws_eip.one]
  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                python3 /home/ubuntu/setting_instance.py
                EOF
  tags = {
    Name = var.INSTANCE_NAME
  }
}
```

The only downside to this code is it creates separate VPC everytime I create an instance. I read in a stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580089/14150764) that we can import an existing VPC using `terraform import` command. Along with the VPC, I had to import the Internet Gateway and Route Table as well (it was throwing error otherwise). But then I wasn't able to access the instance using SSH and also the commands in the user_data part didn't execute (setting_instance.py will send a firebase notification once the instance starts. That's the only purpose of setting_instance.py)

Not only VPC I'd also like to know if I can use the other resources as well to it's fullest extent possible.

I'm new to terraform and AWS. Any suggestions in the above code are welcome.

**EDIT:** Instances are created one at a time according to the need, i.e., whenever there is a need to create a new instance I use this code. In the current scenario if there are already 5 instances running up in a region then I won't be able to use this code to create a 6th instance in the same region when the demand arises.

Comment: So new instances would be exactly same as `resource "aws_instance" "web-server-instance"`?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah. It'd be exactly the same. There are some more commands in the user_data which I've omitted thinking it'd be irrelevant. But yeah every ec2 instance created will be executing the same set of commands.

Answer (score 1):

If as you say, they would be exactly same, the easiest way would be to  use [count](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count), which would indicate how many instance you want to have. For that you can introduce new variable:

```
variable "number_of_instance" {
  default = 1
}
```

and then

```
resource "aws_instance" "web-server-instance" {

  count = var.number_of_instance

  ami               = var.AMI_ID
  instance_type     = "g4dn.xlarge"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
  key_name          = "us-east-2"
  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
  }
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = "200"
  }
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.training_profile.name
  depends_on = [aws_eip.one]
  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                python3 /home/ubuntu/setting_instance.py
                EOF
  tags = {
    Name = var.INSTANCE_NAME
  }
}
```

All this must be manage by same state file, not fully separate state files, as again you will end up with duplicates of the VPC. You only change `number_of_instance` to what you want. For more resilient solution, you would have to use **autoscaling group** for the instances.

Comment: My bad. I should've been clearer. All the instances won't be created simultaneously. They'd be created as and when the demand arises (one by one using the same code). Its just that they'd be identical, the only difference would be in the instance name (set using the iam_instance_profile).